# Using low frequency data to calibrate high frequency data

Tags: matlab, performance, linear-regression, calibration, large-data

I have a 10 Hz time series measured by a fast instrument and a 1 minute time series measured by a slow reference instrument. The data consists of a fluctuating meteorological parameter. The slow reference instrument is used to calibrate the fast instrument measurements. Both time series are synchronised.

My idea:

- Average the 10 Hz data into 1 minute blocks.
- Take 5 one minute block from each time series and calculate the linear regression equations.
- Use the regression equations to calibrate the 10 Hz data in 5 minute blocks (3000 data points).

What would be the best way to match (calibrate) the high frequency data using the low frequency data? I use MATLAB.

More background: The fast instrument outputs a fluctuating voltage signal while the slow instrument outputs the true value of a trace gas concentration in ppb (parts per billion). The slow instrument samples every ten seconds and outputs the average every one minute.

In short I would like to have my fast signal also in ppb but without losing it's integrity (I need the turbulent fluctuations to remain unfiltered), hence the need to use a linear fit.

Comment: what do you mean when you say Calibrate? you want to apply the same regression function to it?

Comment: @GameOfThrows, I think that what buzz want is somethin like: `RefInstrumentData = RegFactor*NewInstrumentData + C` where C can be a systematic error.

Comment: Buzz before that we resolve the problem: are you sur that the correlation between both instruments is linear ? And be careful if you take the average of the 10 Hz instrument over 1 minute, you want to compare the same parameter at the SAME time (ideally) !

Comment: @obchardon When he said match, I thought he was trying to compare how similar 2 vectors of different frequency are (which is why I think he is looking to compare the linear regression of each vector). I guess my question is what sort of result is he looking for, a RMSE or the RegFactor and C you suggested.

Comment: @GameofThrows  The timestamps from the two instruments are perfectly synchronised e.g. 1205 from the fast instrument would coincide with 1205 from the slow instrument - the only difference would be that the fast instrument gives samples while the slow instrument gives one minute averages from 10s samples.      In the end the equation should be Fast_signal_ppb =regfactor*Fast_signal_mV+ regOffset   where regfactor and regOffset are derived from a linear fit between the fast data and the slow data. The units of m would be mV/ppb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach and the results I got...

I modelled the problem as there being

- a real (unmeasured by instruments) signal.
  Let's call this `real`.
- a slow signal - which is just the real signal sampled once a minute.
  Let's call this `lf` (short for low frequency).
- a fast signal - real signal + noise + signal drift.
  Let's call this `hf` (short for high frequency).

The task was to take the slow and fast signals and try to reconstruct the real signal.
(Using least squares as a scoring metric)

### Strategy:

- Define a "piecewise linear filter" - this takes a signal, and returns a piecewise version of it. (With each piecewise part occurring where the slow signal is measured.)
- NOTE: The slow signal is considered piecewise anyway.
- Define a forwards-backwards low pass filter.
- Define "uncertainty" to be 0 at the points where the low frequency signal is measured. It linearly increases to 1 when the timestamp is halfway between low frequency signal measurements.
- Now, take your high frequency signal and filter it with the low pass filter.
  Let's call this `hf_lp`
- Take hf_lp and apply the "piecewise linear filter" to it.
  Let's call this `hf_lp_pl`
- Subtract the last two from each other. 
  I.e. `hf_diff = hf_lp - hf_lp_pl`.
- You now want to find some function that estimates how by how much `hf_diff` should be added to the low frequency signal (`lf`) such that the squared error between `real_estimated` and `real` is minimized.
  I fitted a function along the lines of `real_estimated = lf + diff.*(a1*uncertainty + a2*uncertainty.^2 + a3*uncertainty.^3)`
- Use `fminsearch` or other optimization techniques to get `a1`, `a2`, `a3`...

Here is a sample plot of my results - you can see that `real_estimated` is much closer to `real` than the slow signal `lf`.

[image: Reconstructed estimate from fast and slow]

### Closing thoughts...

- The fast signal contains too much very low frequency (drift) and too much
  very high frequency (noise) components.
  But it has valuable medium frequency info.
- The slow signal has perfect low frequency information, but no medium frequency info.
- The strategy above is really just one way of extracting the medium frequencies from the fast signal and adding it to the low frequency signal.
- This way, we get the best of all worlds: low frequencies, medium frequencies and low noise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate input.  Please have a look at the additional background information that I added to the question.  I would like to avoid filtering the fast signal - would I be able to achieve this with your strategy?

Comment: I believe it should. Drop me some data somewhere on pastebin/github/etc and I'll see how well my code handles it...
Regarding filtering, I'll just remove the filter part and keep the regression part.

Comment: To make things a bit easier to visualize, I've scaled the fast instrument to have the same mean and standard deviation as the slow instrument. Here is the result: http://imgur.com/xchbEWw. From the data it seems your fast instrument is too noisy to provide a valuable contribution :(. It only makes the data "look" more realistic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the time and effort you took. I hope this solution will help someone else facing similar problems.  The 'noise' is expected (and required) as it represents the result of a gas-phase reaction under turbulent conditions.